# how to specify the width of a menu option in percentage html/css?

Tags: html, css

New to html/css and am creating a simple web page. Creating a horizontal menu by taking a un-ordered list and removing bullets, floating left etc... How do I specify the width of a menu option in percentage. Say I have a 5 menu options and I want each one to take up 20% of the screen. How do I do this, currently when I try to specify the width in percentages, it takes a percentage of how big the link is, not how big the screen is.

Comment: `width: 20%`. Pleeeease do some research before asking

Comment: width: 20% doesn't work, it makes the width 20% of the link element, not the width of the screen

Comment: try to create main div with 100% and then give width:20% to each menu.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works:

```
<style>
    ul.menu{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    li.menu{
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```